# Problem with roave/security-advisories when update symfony 4 to 5

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to update my Symfony 4.4.19 to Symfony 5.x but i've got two conflicts who are blocking the process:
symfony/monolog-bundle and roave/security-advisories

I'm running method `composer update "symfony/*" --with-all-dependencies`
In Symfony documentation about [upgrading](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html#update-to-the-new-major-version-via-composer), it is clearly specified that "*A few libraries starting with symfony/ follow their own versioning scheme. You do not need to update these versions: you can upgrade them independently whenever you want*"  and the example is...symfony/monolog-bundle

```sh
Updating dependencies
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/monolog-bundle ^3.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/monolog-bundle[v3.6.0].
    - symfony/monolog-bundle v3.6.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ~3.4 || ~4.0 || ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.11].
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.11.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.10.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.9.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.8.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.7.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.6.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.5.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.4.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.3.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.2.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.1.
    - roave/security-advisories dev-latest conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v5.0.0.
    - roave/security-advisories is locked to version dev-latest and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Here's my composer.json where i've replaced all 4.4 to 5.0 :

```json
{
    "type": "project",
    "version": "1.2.0",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "abraham/twitteroauth": "^1.1",
        "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "^1.5",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.7",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^3.0",
        "gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle": "^0.9.1",
        "hamhamfonfon/astrobin-ws": "^2.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^3.3",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.6",
        "ruflin/elastica": "^6.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
        "symfony/asset": "^5.0",
        "symfony/console": "^5.0",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^5.0",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^5.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.11",
        "symfony/form": "^5.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^5.0",
        "symfony/google-mailer": "5.0",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.0",
        "symfony/intl": "^5.0",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.6",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.2",
        "symfony/process": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/requirements-checker": "^1.1",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^5.0",
        "symfony/serializer": "^5.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.0",
        "symfony/templating": "^5.0",
        "symfony/translation": "^5.0",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.0",
        "symfony/validator": "^5.0",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "^5.0",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5"
    },
    //...
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.0.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "roave/security-advisories": "dev-latest",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.12",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.0"
    }
}
```

I've made a "composer update" just before replacing 4.4 by 5.0 to be sure to be on the lastest version on 4.4.x version.

Comment: I always find it useful to create a fresh project (in this case 5.2) and then require the third party stuff one at a time to see what happens.  In this case I ended up with         "roave/security-advisories": "9999999-dev",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not really in monolog-bundle but as follows:

- monolog-bundle requires symfony/http-kernel ~3.4 || ~4.0 || ^5.0
- You restricted all Symfony components to 5.0 (by setting "extra" -> "symfony" -> "require" to 5.0.*). So the only fulfillable requirement for monolog-bundle is http-kernel 5.0.*
- roave/security-advisories works by purposely conflicting with lib versions that have known security issues. In this case, every 5.0.* release has vulnerability CVE-2020-15094 (see https://symfony.com/blog/cve-2020-15094-prevent-rce-when-calling-untrusted-remote-with-cachinghttpclient) and is therefore blocked. So there is no valid version left and Composer aborts.

My suggestion: Symfony 5.0 reached end of life, so use the current release Symfony 5.2.x (Composer constraint "^5.2"). As Symfony uses strict Semantic Versioning there is no disadvantage for going to 5.2 instead of 5.0 (i.e. all code that runs on 5.0 will also run on 5.2).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It looks ok with your solution. There are some yaml to update (e.g: "framework: template" not exist anymore...).
I don't know if it's a problem, juste `composer recipes:install symfony/framework-bundle --force -v` (and other recepes return errors) but when i do composer info on package, i've 5.2.x version. So maybe it's not very serious.

Comment: The templating option was already removed on 5.0 so this would have been also a problem if you did the smaller step. The suggested upgrade path for Symfony is: 1. Upgrade to the latest release within a major version (4.4 in your case which you did). 2. Remove all deprecated features as described in the UPGRADE document in the Symfony repo. 3. Upgrade to the new major release. This should very much guarantee a smooth transition. Good luck :-)